# PHP arrays/ form post

Tags: php, forms, html-table, html-email

I have asked this before here, but I'm not sure, if the question was clear enough, or right. So now I ask again, the solution I have is not 100% right!

I have a form and I submit it, there is a table in it.
Each line of the table has a checkbox that you can check for ordering a product,  a select field for a charge for the product and of course the price (in a select field, so I have  a value for the price).

The goal to achieve is to have blocks in the mail, like this (below):

```
product: greek salad xl
quantity: 4pcs.
price: 5.50$

product: tomatos
quantity: 8pcs.
price: 2.50$

....
```

so I have this, but the price is always taken from the first element, so,  if I chose the second and third product: the price is taken from the first. The quantity is taken from the first -  it is shifted one.

What can I do?

This is the (simple) foreach PHP setup that I have tried (and many other variations):

```
$product = $_POST['bestellung']; --> this is the checkbox that is  correct!
$quantity = $_POST['menge']; --> always shifted...
$price = $_POST['liq_preis']; --> always shifted...

foreach( $product as $key => $item ) {
$bestell_tab .= "\n\nProdukt: $item  \n\nStueckzahl: ".$quantity[$key]." \n\nPreis: ".$price[$key].";
}
```

(the $bestell_tab I put in the PHP mail for submit ...)

If somebody can help a php-greenhorn with a "simple" solution, it would be great!

Here HTML Markup:

```
<select class="kat-preis" name="liq_preis[]"><option value="10.00">10.00</option></select>
<select class="1-100" name="menge[]"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>
<input type="checkbox" name="bestellung[]" value="expl-tomatos">
```

**Edit**

```
array(14) {
["tablepress-23_length"]=>
string(2) "10"
["menge"]=>
array(6) {
[0]=>
string(1) "1"
[1]=>
string(1) "2"
[2]=>
string(1) "2"
[3]=>
string(1) "2"
[4]=>
string(1) "2"
[5]=>
string(1) "2"
}
["liq_preis"]=>
array(6) {
[0]=>
string(4) "1.00"
[1]=>
string(4) "2.00"
[2]=>
string(4) "3.00"
[3]=>
string(4) "4.00"
[4]=>
string(4) "5.00"
[5]=>
string(4) "6.00"
}
["bestellung"]=>
array(5) {
[0]=>
string(9) "tomatos109"
[1]=>
string(9) "tomatos111"
[2]=>
string(9) "tomatos116"
[3]=>
string(9) "tomatos118"
[4]=>
string(9) "tomatos209"
}
```

In this, I have clicked on the 2nd Product. The first is empty, but the value isn't right. It is only for the product name "bestellung" right

**Edit**

```
<td class="column-1">51234</td><td class="column-2">goodchoice</td><td class="column-3">tomatos from Spain</td><td class="column-4"><select class="kat-preis" name="liq_preis[]"><option value="1.00">10.00</option></select></td><td class="column-5">1.00 CHF</td><td class="column-6"><select class="1-100" name="menge[]"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select></td><td class="column-7"><input type="checkbox" name="bestellung[]" value="51234"> </td>
```

Comment: what does your html look like

Comment: it is a normal form that is working... (in it is a table, generated with the tablepress plugin 4 wordpress) at the end, it is a normal table in a form, thats it. you think is a html thing?

Comment: Yes it could be for example you need to make sure you have brackets `[]` on your name attribute in order to send arrays to the server

Comment: yes, brackets i have, see my edit

Comment: Can you update with a var_dump($_POST); ?

Comment: @Mr Jack  @meda  -  have updated my post with a `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: I also notice that in your string in the foreach you are missing a closing "

Comment: The code works for me by the way, there is no problem once it compiles. So that means there is something you are not showing that is breaking it or your post data was not the scenario you describe.

Comment: Put full html (im pretty sure I know what you are doing wrong and that is in html) - basically put item name as key for your two extra arrays.

Comment: the closing bracket, you mean? thats not. (see above, is not in the code...) when i replace `$key` with `$item`, then i get nothing good.

Comment: @Mr Jack - Can you take a look again? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The php code becomes:

```
product = $_POST['bestellung']; --> this is the checkbox that is  correct!
$quantity = $_POST['menge']; --> allways shifted...
$price = $_POST['liq_preis']; --> allways shifted...

foreach( $product as $item ) {
$bestell_tab .= "\n\nProdukt: ".$item."  \n\n
Stueckzahl: ".$quantity[$item]." \n\n
Preis: ".$price[$item];//here there was an error in original code - an extra "   
}
```

For the above to work, you must put the value of the bestsellung in the array of the other two. How will the user know it is tomatoes though? Anyhow, the html becomes:

```
<table>
<td class="column-1">51234</td>
<td class="column-2">goodchoice</td>
<td class="column-3">tomatos from Spain</td>
<td class="column-4">
    <select class="kat-preis" name="liq_preis[51234]">
        <option value="1.00">10.00</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td class="column-5">1.00 CHF</td>
<td class="column-6">
    <select class="1-100" name="menge[51234]">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td class="column-7">
    <input type="checkbox" name="bestellung[]" value="51234"> 
</td>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks man, it seems to work. - for me the solution is that what i searched, but just for better understanding: there was a other solution for this? - so that i d'ont have to fill out over 100 values in my table? ($product as $key => $item) but i will try next time something to learn more. again: thx !

Comment: the point is, i d'ont can bring a empty line after each block, for better reading.

Comment: Well, the "better" way is to load the data with a loop from a database. That way you do it once and let the program do the 100 times.

Comment: if you dont want an empty line, remove one \n